# How to manipulate a datasource in SketchFlow

Tags: c#, blend, sketchflow

I'm learning SketchFlow and am working with a sample project I've created.  The basic idea I'm wanting to prototype is having a list of beverages (which are bound to some sample data) and allowing the user to add one or more to their order.  When they click the add to order button the selected beverage from the listbox would be added to the order listbox on the right.

[image: Screenshot]

Perhaps I'm overthinking this, but there doesnt seem to be an easy way to do it without the marjority of it being done in the code behind.

Or is this something that shouldn't be prototyped in sketchflow?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to bind it the right list with new datasource instead, cause the idea here is not to write and get involved into coding more than its a protoype tool, so try to get around by bind the right list to new datasource which include the list u added from the left hand side